# How to use GetModuleHandle() from JNA properly?

Tags: java, cursor, mouse, jna

I am looking into using JNA to change the mouse cursor while running an application. Currently, I am just trying to the cursor and I have gotten as far as the code below. The problem I have is getting an HINSTANCE object to to pass to LoadCursor(), so that I can get a HCURSOR object to use in SetCursor(). I know that HMOD and HINSTANCE are the same thing from the User32 library so thats why I using HMODULE.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I am absolutely lost from here.

I get this error whenever I run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'GetModuleHandle': The specified procedure could not be found.

```
import com.sun.jna.*;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.*;

public class changeMouse {
   public interface User32 extends Library {
      User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);
      HWND GetForegroundWindow();
      HCURSOR SetCursor(HCURSOR cursor);
      HCURSOR LoadCursor(HINSTANCE hIn, String lp);
   }

   public interface Kernel32 extends Library {
      Kernel32 INSTANCE = (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary("kernel32", Kernel32.class);
      HMODULE GetModuleHandle(String name);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      User32 user32 = User32.INSTANCE;
      HMODULE hmod = Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetModuleHandle(null);
   }
}
```

Comment: Can't you use the `jna-platform` library for this instead of rolling your own?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel How do I do that? Aren't I already using the jna-platform?

Comment: No, JNA is split in two libraries: `jna` (which is the base functionality) and `jna-platform`, which provides JNA-wrappers for OS-specific libraries like Kernel32